# jQuery mobile dialog disappears for google maps api long loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm running into issues with a pseudo-splash page I'm using in jQuery Mobile (it's a programmatically opened dialog on load) when Google Maps API takes too long to load.

Effectively whats happening is that when Google Maps takes a while to finish loading, the jQuery Mobile dialog window disappears, the url still shows #&ui-state=dialog as if it were still open, so it's not closing it, just making it disappear.

I've tried any number of things and I'm not sure how to work around or prevent it.

```
$("#map_canvas").ready(function() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center:latLngVar,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI:true,
        zoomControlOptions:{ position:google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP }
    };

    if(firstShow){

        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var winWidth = $(window).width();
        var oMod = winHeight/winWidth;
        if ( oMod <= 1 ){
            renderLandscape(winHeight,winWidth);
        }else if( oMod > 1 ){
            renderPortrait(winHeight,winWidth);
        }
        drawMap(myOptions);
    }

    showHomeScreen();

    splashListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$("#dlgSplash").click()}, 500);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(splashListener);
    })

    firstShow = false;
});
```

in the html is an anchor tag like so

```
<a href="splash.php" data-prefetch data-rel="dialog" id="dlgSplash" style="display: none;"></a>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Apologies, code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post the code you are using to show the jQuery Mobile dialog and close it? The following should work to accomplish your goal:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function() {
    $("#dialog").popup("open");
});

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
    $("#dialog").popup("close");
}

</script>
```

Comment: this seems like it would allow me to close the dialog programmatically, but I'm trying to prevent that, since it seems to be disappearing when I don't want it to.